# Sharing text with image to instagram using android intent

Tags: java, android, instagram, sharing

I know that this question has been asked several times before, I am trying to add caption to image shared to instagram using send intent

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"YOUR TEXT TO SHARE IN INSTAGRAM");
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
return shareIntent;
```

Has someone ever managed to make it work?

Is it not supported or has the support been revoked?

Comment: The `ACTION_SEND` procotol is documented to support *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM` on any given `Intent`. While some apps might support both, there is no requirement that any app do so.

Comment: Someone stated that Instagram did support text extra while I can not manage to make it work, so I am asking particularly about instagram app

Answer (score 13):

[There was an official statement from Instagram (mid-2015)](http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing) announcing that pre-populated captions would no longer be accepted in the iOS and Android apps:

> Beginning today, the iOS Hooks and Android Intents will stop accepting captions passed by third party apps. This is a non-breaking change: existing mobile apps that utilize pre-filled captions will continue to be able to use this flow to share media through the Instagram apps, but now Instagram will ignore the caption text. To create a caption for a photo or video shared by a third party app, users will have to enter a caption manually, the same way they already do when sharing content using the Instagram native apps.

Looking at [the Instagram documentation for Android](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/), indeed we see that there's no mention of providing the conventional `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` string extra in the intent as is customary for other apps. Their sample is limited to only providing a Uri:

```
// Add the URI to the Intent.
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

// Broadcast the Intent.
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
```

I'm sorry to say that it simply isn't possible, and we're at the discretion of Facebook in making this decision.

Answer (score 7):

Until it`s not solved by Instagram, I copy the text to the clipboard and instruct the user to paste it

Comment: That's a nice aproach. I will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with the same problem. I think is not possible at this time.

In https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/ only talk about Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, so i suppose that it's the only available.

Here is my code:

```
    Intent instagramIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    instagramIntent.setType("image/*");
    File media = new File(mediaPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);
    instagramIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    instagramIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

    PackageManager packManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager.queryIntentActivities(instagramIntent,  PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    boolean resolved = false;
    for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo: resolvedInfoList){
        if(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.instagram.android")){
            instagramIntent.setClassName(
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.name );
            resolved = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(resolved){
        startActivity(instagramIntent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(PromocionarMain.this, "Instagram App is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Please DO NOT copy&paste old posts

Answer (score 0):

Instagram have stopped accepting pre-populated capitions to increase the quality of content in the system. See this post.

http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_.