# Sharing only an image to Instagram and an image + text to WhatsApp, Telegram and other apps

Tags: android, share

I am trying to share an image and caption to other apps using intents. I can do so in [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp) and [Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software)) using the following code:

```java
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(localFile);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Poster"));
```

It works completely fine for WhatsApp and telegram, but when I choose [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram), it opens at first and close by showing a toast saying "not supported format".

By reading documentation I found out that Instagram does not support prepopulated  captions.

So I only want to send the image to Instagram and image + text to other apps. How can I do so?

Comment: have a good read at answers [In this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640765/sharing-text-with-image-to-instagram-using-android-intent).

Comment: @blackapps and ADM instagram is opening at first and closes saying not supported format and I come back to my app. I want to share contents according to the app that user selects.